# How to run a background installation of a program?

Tags: installation, windows

How can I install any application/program in the background without any installer pop up or user intervention on windows?

After the successful installation the user must be notified.

Is this even possible at all?

Also ideas on how to pass the installation parameters (user inputs) to the installation process will be appreciated.

Comment: We can copy executable files. Please check overview section of this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installation_%28computer_programs%29

Answer (score 0):

Check [NSIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System). It's a scriptable install system. We use it since years and install our software without any issues.

Comment: Is it possible without any involvement of a third party software?

Comment: We don't use third party stuff here. We copy files, write registry entries, deciding what to do depending on environment variables and whatever. It's pretty flexible.

Comment: Will it be possible for me to run any software/application (irrespective of it's size) in the background with NSIS. Since i'm not able to download this software on my campus due to firewall restrictions and I have to raise a request to my campus system admin. So wanted to clarify whether this tool supports only small sized applications before I go and raise the request.

Comment: 1. We use `ExecWait` in our NSIS scripts to run `cmd.exe /c...` or batch files. So i assume you can start any kind of software during installation. 2. our NSIS packages are sized up to 800 MB. The installed size of the cad system from that package is about 1G. No problems until now with the file size.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced Installation Package will help you by setting `LIMITUI` property inside the MSI.
You can check this link for more information [INSTALLER_LINK](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-silent-install.html)

Comment: Is it possible without any involvement of a third party software like the one you suggested?

Comment: may be through Visual studio installer project. I am using NSIS for installer exe